# TWebBrowser e HttpOnly cookie

Tags: delphi, cookies

Como obter o HttpOnly cookie do TWebBrowser?
ao fazer login em uma pagina pelo IE, Firefox, ou chrome vejo o seguinte cookie:

**Cookie:_ga=GA1.3.2133370562.1518083464; _gid=GA1.3.1396320410.1518629322; _gat=1; JSESSIONID=Qfh5hG0TWtphv6N2B6MT57d561RQzGqRLCb0B1322Kz49pp1R44g!1012588258!NONE**

Já o TWebBroser me mostra somente

**Cookie:_ga=GA1.3.2133370562.1518083464; _gid=GA1.3.1396320410.1518629322; _gat=1**

Falta o JSESSIONID, verifiquei que é por questões de segurança, mais vi que tem jeito de obter, mais o que achei não funcionou, alguma ideia?

Comment: `mais o que achei não funcionou` cade???

Answer (score 0):

Depois de muito procurar encontrei a solução, segue para quem precisar:

```
const
  INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 8192;
var
  hModule: THandle;
  lp: Pointer;
  InternetGetCookieEx: function(lpszUrl, lpszCookieName, lpszCookieData
    : PAnsiChar; var lpdwSize: DWORD; dwFlags: DWORD; lpReserved: pointer)
    : BOOL; stdCall;
  CookieSize: DWORD;
  CookieData: PAnsiChar;
begin
  LoadLibrary('wininet.dll');
  hModule := GetModuleHandle('wininet.dll');
  if hModule <> 0 then
  begin
    @InternetGetCookieEx := GetProcAddress(hModule, 'InternetGetCookieExA');
    if @InternetGetCookieEx <> nil then
    begin
      CookieSize := 1024;
      Cookiedata := AllocMem(CookieSize);
      if InternetGetCookieEx(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(host)), nil, Cookiedata, CookieSize, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, nil) then
      result:=cookiedata;
      FreeMem(Cookiedata);
    end;
  end;
end;
```